# How to maintain 2 repositories in SAP WebIDE?

Tags: git, sapui5, sap-web-ide

Scenario: I just had a go-live for SAP ui5 application. Now during the hyper care week, I don’t want to commit any changes of the upcoming sprint else will need to back them if urgent change needs to be pushed to prod.

There are multiple developers who will be working during next sprint and my challenge is- how to pull/push our changes in upcoming spring from all the developers without affecting the original application.

Also as we want testers to do some regression testing how to give them this application with new changes? For example, app A has all the changes that went to prod, now if tester wants to test the new changes, do we make a new temp app and deploy to it?

And lastly, once out of hyper care how to merge both the repositories. I know there are blogs on git web ide for the same, but either I did not read the correct blog or I need help with an example. I understand this is exactly the reason why we use GIT, but I think I have never been in this situation before.

Comment: use different branches in git and leave Master alone. try to not build and deploy.

Comment: So I should create some other "DEV" repository - it should be remote branch correct ?

Comment: I'd make development branches in the same repository. developers don't need to deploy, they can run the app in webide from the branch. If you really need to deploy, just deploy from the branch. Break fixes - switch back to master branch, deploy and transport. Merge dev branch into master branch when development is done.

Comment: I created a remote branch and other developer even committed and pushed changes to that remote branch. But now when another developer is trying to do so he is getting non-fast forward error. I checked online, solution is to merge repo, but I am not sure which repo I need to merge now.

Comment: i would recommend https://learngitbranching.js.org/, these are basic git features... i have to admit that the webIDE provides maybe a limited UI for some of the examples